# Will a Soligor 28-200 mm lens fit on a Canon T3i body?

Tags: adapter

[image]I just bought an MC Soligor c/d zoom +macro f=28-200mm 1:3.8-5.5 72  no . 885209026 lens.
I own a Canon EOS Rebel T3i. Is it possible to mount this lens on my camera, and if so, what kind of adapter do I need?
 I think the mount  42

Comment: You need to know what mount the lens was designed for. Is it possible for you to post some pictures of the lens itself, particularly the mount (the bit which connects to the camera)?

Comment: The lens is a manual focus push-pull zoom that predates all of the AF mounts; it should be adaptable with a glassless adapter (Canon FD, Minolta MC/MD, Oly OM, Pentax K and Nikon F all have longer flange distances than the EF/EF-S mount, and the Soligor was made for all of them). You will have to know the mount it was made for to decide which adapter to get. And you may well be disappointed with the quality of the lens unless you keep the final image sizes small; it was a bargain lens in its day, and all lenses are better now than they were then.

Comment: @StanRogers FD has a shorter flange distance than EF.

Answer (score 1):

Your image could be taken a bit more from the side to show the mount better, but it looks like screwmount. If it is M42 you are in luck. You can just get one of these adapters with AF confirm chip:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-M42-Lens-to-Canon-EOS-Adapter-AF-Confirm-Chips-Mount-Adaptor-Ring-UK-/290800227405?pt=UK_Photography_CameraLenses_Lens_caps_hoods_adaptors_ET&hash=item43b50b544d

If it is M39 you need "Active" adapting (with a lens), which is not recommended.

Note: Vintage lenses primes are awesome, but the technology for zooms was not so evolved. So modern lenses evolved greatly in the zooms, lesser so in primes, making vintage primes good buys. Some of them have very distinctive looks as well.